# Question about listing all possible combination given n and k (Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x

Good day. I was searching for how to list all possible combinations of numbers 1 to n taken k numbers. I cam across some algorithms and recursive methods. But I am fairly new to coding so I have a hard time understanding complex codes. Can someone tell me a way I can think of this problem so that I can put it into code? I am not allowed to use intertools so I may have to do an iterative or recursive version.

```
all_combination(3 , 2)
```

should return

```
[[1,2],[1,3],[2,3]]
```

Comment: The problem is called "Combinations N choose K". It is not trivial. One reference (not simple): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/127704/algorithm-to-return-all-combinations-of-k-elements-from-n

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
from itertools import combinations 
list(combinations(range(1,n+1), k))
```

putting n=3, k=2 produces:

```
[(1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 3)]
```

Comment: Standard library for the win :-)

Comment: @TonySuffolk66 Yeah, fortunately only "intertools" is forbidden.

Comment: Why - it is part of the standard language ? Banning it's use seems perverse to me.